# Close and merge these science vs. philosophy duplicates?

Tags: discussion

##### [What is the relationship between philosophy and science?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/1506) appears to be the mother thread. Many users have flagged the following as duplicates that have yet to be closed and merged. [Conifold](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/64144/can-mathematics-and-physics-be-thought-of-as-branches-of-philosophy#comment177144_64144)

1. [Are philosophy and science mergeable today?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/34438)
2. [How is Philosophy related to Science?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/49429)
3. [What is the historical relationship between physics and philosophy?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/64584)

##### [Dan Hicks](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/46708/knowing-whether-a-discipline-is-science-or-philosophy?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment117952_46708)

4. [What is the relationship between philosophy and science?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/1506)
5. [Is science just a more refined and effective method of philosophy?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/24316)

##### [Chris Sunami](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/46708/knowing-whether-a-discipline-is-science-or-philosophy?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment118121_46708)

6. [What is the difference between philosophy, religion, and science?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/43233)
7. [What happens to a philosophical question when it is solved for good?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/23363)
8. [How is philosophical reasoning different from scientific or logical reasoning?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/36131)

##### [DBK](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/527/does-philosophy-belong-to-empirical-science-or-formal-science?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment6590_527)

9. [Does philosophy belong to empirical science or formal science?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/527)

#### I am uncertain why [Philosophy is the mother of all science](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/24699) got closed as "off-topic"? Ought it be closed as duplicate?

### I forgot which but definitely I remember seeing a post here on Philosophy SE that showed  "merged" at the top (not "closed"). Can anyone find these posts on Philosophy SE? Math SE [showcases this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4404789).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My take on this is that it might be useful to write an *authoritative version* of this question, make it community wiki, and perhaps link to older questions/close in favor of the canonical one — at which point interested parties could maybe iterate more cooperatively. It definitely diffuses the answering-power of the community if the “same” problem is repeated so frequently.

Comment: Do we need another "authoritative version"??? See my edited post.

Answer (score 0):

I concur with @JosephWeissman on this, especially seeing that as far as I am aware, you cannot actually merge questions in the sense you are talking about. Writing an authoritative question and answer set with links into the questions you are talking about, will merge the questions you raise into one question, and provide a way to efficiently link future same questions as duplicates.

Comment: "as far as I am aware, you cannot actually merge questions in the sense you are talking about" Truly? Pls see my edit.

Comment: Oh @user35395. You learn something new every day 